# apt update message : /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist - invalid file name extension

Tags: extension, filename

When I run `sudo apt update` I receive the following message: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist` has an invalid file name extension. This has also started giving me an error message every now and then.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ls -l /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

Answer (score 4):

There was an **update** for the `unattended-upgrades` package on November, 17th / 2016, which might have caused this problem, because this file did not exist before. The correct and relevant `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` file is still in place. To get rid of the message, remove the file by running this command : `sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist`

Here is the correct content of the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` folder, you can check it by executing :

```
ls -l /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Okt 13 15:38 00aptitude
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Okt 13 15:37 00trustcdrom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  769 Okt  4 19:43 01autoremove
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 3160 Nov 10 10:19 01autoremove-kernels
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   42 Okt  4 19:43 01-vendor-ubuntu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 Okt 13 16:09 10periodic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108 Jul 12  2013 15update-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   85 Jul 12  2013 20archive
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 Okt 13 16:09 20auto-upgrades
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  243 Dez 16  2009 20dbus
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1040 Mai 19  2016 20packagekit
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1438 Sep 16 13:16 50appstream
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2554 Nov 18 07:26 50unattended-upgrades
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  182 Apr 27  2016 70debconf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  305 Jul 12 00:02 99update-notifier
```

This is the output after removing the invalid file and upgrading the Ubuntu 16.10 system today.

Update : I tested whether this was a single exceptional issue on another machine which runs the same system and no, it is showing the same behavior, so most probably it is the package update.